# Результаты отзывов участников за 2017 год

Tags: поддержка

Во время новогодних праздников участники сообщества могут оставлять отзыв о работе компании и атмосфере в сообществе за прошедший год. Прежде всего хочу выразить огромную благодарность всем, кто выделил время, чтобы поделиться своими мыслями и идеями с нами, а значит, сделать сайт еще лучше для себя и коллег!

Обычно мы просматриваем все оставленные отзывы, обсуждаем их, составляем краткую выдержку. Но на этот раз я бы хотел поделиться с сообществом частью оставленных отзывов. В этом году нужно было ответить на 4 вопроса, и мы получили 14 отзывов. Ниже представлены вопросы и наиболее интересные ответы к ним.

Пожалуйста, не волнуйтесь, если вы не увидели ваш отзыв ниже! Он был получен и рассмотрен. В этом вопросе представлены лишь краткие итоги.

Answer (score 8):

#### Пожалуйста, подскажите, какие технические нововведения или процессы организации сообщества смогут сделать ваше участие в сообществе легче, приятнее, продуктивнее?

Принявшие участие в опросе участники рекомендуют не останавливаться на достигнутом и активнее развивать движок. Например, систему ассоциаций вопросов между сайтами, чаще обновлять статистику, добавить элемент игры.

Были и технические замечания. Например, обновить систему работы с фрагментами кода:

- добавить возможность добавлять sass\scss;
- добавить возможность запускать примеры кода на C++ и Java.

Респонденты также рекомендовали внести изменения в дизайн сайта:

- Добавить страничку (либо преобразовать главную), где будет возможность создать выборку вопросов с сайтов на разных языках. (Если я правильно понял вопрос, то сделать фильтр вопросов с разных сайтов можно уже сейчас на [обзорном сайте сети](https://stackexchange.com/) в разделе «Filtered Questions».)
- Добавить больше анимаций :)
- Добавить подсказки о механиках сайта во все мыслимые и немыслимые места! Сайт достаточно сложный, чтобы разобраться в нем, нужен не один день. С другой стороны, нам, как опытным участникам, хотелось бы чтобы уже первый вопрос или ответ был опубликован с соблюдением основных правил сообщества.
- На тему обучения новых участников было очень хорошее предложение — ввести инициативу «Подсказка недели»:

  - написать набор простых подсказок и рекомендаций по использованию сайта на Мете;
  - для каждой подсказки сделать баннер, добавить его в ротацию на нашем сайте;
  - раз в неделю менять подсказку, на которую мы ссылаемся.

Также ребята обратили внимание на то, что в сортировке «интересных» вопросов иногда случается, что самое интересное не всегда получает верхние позиции в выборке.

#### Чего сегодня не хватает сообществу, по вашему мнению? Какие проблемы в сообществе вы видите?

Новые допустимые темы для сайта. Участники хотят видеть вопросы на разные темы, не всегда напрямую относящиеся к программированию (например, дизайн или обработка изображений).

Далее практически все отзывы можно поделить попалам (более или менее в равной пропорции):

- Первый лагерь составляют участники, которым не нравится слишком лоальяное отношение к новичкам, к учащимся, то есть к тем, кто публикует слишком простые, на их взгляд, задачки, не проявив достаточного подтверждения детального изучения контекста проблемы.
- Вторая группа респондентов говорит о том, что сайт слишком враждебен к новичкам и надо ослабить правила закрытия и удаления вопросов, проявлять больше лояльности к тем, кто задает простые вопросы.

На мой взгляд, правда где–то посередине! Что самое важное — обе группы выражают желание видеть больше интересных развернутых ответов. Участники уверены, что это система с обратной связью: без качественных развернутых ответов нам не увидеть хороших вопросов! Что ж, в этом вопросе все зависит только от нас!

#### Что, по вашему мнению, необходимо сделать, чтобы сообщество динамично развивалось?

На мой взгляд, крайне интересная мысль, особенно в контексте предыдущего пункта:

> Однозначно исключить пиар сообщества в любой его форме. Полезные для сообщества люди наверняка смогут самостоятельно найти сюда дорогу, а привлекать "всех подряд" не стоит.

Хочу также выделить следующий отзыв:

> ... Можно было бы ещё больше участников привлечь, уделяя больше внимания пресечению разного рода нападок и оскорблений со стороны некоторых участников по отношению друг к другу.

По моему мнению, Stack Overflow на русском — самое дружелюбное сообщество в Рунете. Наша система ценностей стоит на взаимном общечеловеческом уважении друг к другу, без которого теряется весь смысл, а «неравнодушное к проблемам коллег сообщество» становится безразличной группой людей. Это крайне важное замечание!

Было несколько отзывов примерно об одном: нам следует тратить больше усилий на обучение новых участников правилам сообщества. Обучать лично, публиковать обучающие материалы на внешних ресурсах, проводить конкурсы на использование разных механик сайта. Один из возможных походов, по мнению респондентов, — проявлять больше бдительности и последующей строгости к выполнению правил как задающими, так и отвечающими, то есть требовать не только правильно написанный вопрос, но и не поощрять тех, кто отвечает нехотя.

#### Что–то еще. Напишите здесь все, что бы вы хотели сказать компании в свободной форме. Если ваше сообщение адресовано конкретному сотруднику, пожалуйста, укажите его/ее имя или псевдоним на сайтах сети Stack Exchange.

Как ни странно, были лишь теплые слова. Огромное спасибо вам за них!

> - Спасибо всем модераторам и участникам. За этот год, наконец-то, обновился дизайн, стал более приятным и удобным. Появилось больше участников, а значит больше помощи в некоторых вопросах.
> - Спасибо всем профессионалам за то, что помогают становиться профессионалами и нам. Успехов сайту в новом году!
> - Всех с Новым годом, а отцам-основателям -- спасибо за труды :)
> - Хочу сказать всем причастным огромное спасибо, за то что ruSO есть! (и еще большее thank you to all the SO/SE stuff!!)

---

Хочу еще раз поблагодарить всех, кто поделился с нами наболевшим. Ваши отзывы будут обязательно услышаны! Мы (компания) начнем их обсуждение уже на ближайшей планерке во вторник. Надеюсь, вы останетесь довольны результатам!

Comment: *ввести инициативу «Подсказка недели»* -- о, это дело. Возможно, стоит даже держать некоторые баннеры в ротации постоянно. Или даже сделать отдельный баннер в правой панели исключительно для советов, с собственным пулом (а-ля "социальная реклама"). С нетерпением жду выделенного вопроса по этой теме, как только и если компания даст зелёный свет.

Comment: @D-side Баннеры у нас уже есть, мы можем добавить что–то в ротацию уже сейчас (никто не заметит). Осталось дело за малым, написать интересные не перегруженные «подсказки» :)

Comment: _добавить возможность запускать примеры кода на C++ и Java_ эт как? 0_о чего бы уж тогда не на всех языках?

Comment: @DaemonHK: язык может быть на клиенте (в браузере) реализован. К примеру, для Питона http://www.skulpt.org/ ¶  Можно на сторонние сервисы опираться такие как http://pythontutor.com/ (компиляция и исполнение на сервере), допускает [встраивание в свои страницы](https://github.com/pgbovine/OnlinePythonTutor/blob/master/v5-unity/pytutor-embed-demo.html) или http://repl.it (в прошлом в браузере тяжёлая реализация на emscripten) и [mybinder.org позволяют ссылки на интерактивные примеры вставлять в ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/762842/23044) (код на сервере выполняется)¶

Comment: про вторую группу: ваше описание демонстрирует отсутствие понимания позиции этой группы. Что крайне печально, т.к. эта группа представляет интересы, что мне кажется является миссией/видением сайта: "сделать интернет лучше".  Если вы видение сайта не будете защищать, то кто? Ключевое отличие между группами: одна группа говорит -- "ты тунеядец, я не буду на твои вопросы отвечать". Другая группа говорит: "имеет значение полезность вопроса для будущих посетителей из гугла, имеет значение интересность вопроса для людей, которые отвечают на вопросы, не имеет значения *кто* и почему задал вопрос"

Comment: это тонкое отличие, но крайне существенное: одна группа на людях акцентирует (что нездоровую атмосферу в комментариях к вопросам создаёт "а сам-то ты что сделал"), другая -- как улучшить **содержимое** вопросов/ответов ("в вопросе/ответе такая-то проблема, вот шаги как улучшить его").

Comment: Это непростая проблема. К примеру, вот дискуссия между основателями в 2011: [SE Podcast #20 (10 минут можно пропустить)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/09/28/se-podcast-20/) (Jeff боится, что слишком простые вопросы, отпугнут опытных людей от сайта. Joel боится, что злоупотреблять будут, если инструменты дать типа "general reference"/lmgtfy)

Comment: проблема с первой группой, в том что они говорят "мне не нравится автор вопроса и поэтому я не дам тебе возможность ответить на вопрос и соответственно я не дам возможность другим людям с похожей проблемой найти этот вопрос в будущем (в гугле)". Вторая группа не за ослабление стандартов, а за использование конструктивных критериев оценки (оценивать полезность содержимого вопроса, а не моральный облик автора).

Comment: Коллеги, пожалуйста, обратите внимание на инициативу по созданию подсказок: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7022/