# Как должны выглядеть подсказки о механиках сайта?

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, подсказки-на-сайте

В конце года каждый участник [мог оставить отзыв и предложение по дальнейшему развитию сообщества](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6653/). Из [отзывов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6783/) видно, что многие участники считают механики сайта сложными, особенно для новичков, которые только что присоединились и хотят опубликовать свой первый вопрос.

Спешу предложить развить предложенную в отзывах идею создания набора подсказок и рекомендаций о работе сайта. Для этого предлагаю создать два вопроса. В этом вопросе рассмотреть саму идею, набор тем для подсказок и другие мысли о инициативе. [Во втором вопросе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7020/6) собрать готовые рекомендации в ответах. Именно на ответы второго вопроса в дальнейшем будут ссылаться графические баннеры на основном сайте.

### Основная идея

#### Структура

Вектором, на который можно ориентироваться, мы можем считать «[Способы обхода неоднозначных ограничений движка на Stack Overflow](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3392/)». Как мне кажется, если мы структурируем итоговый вопрос с рекомендации в неком аналогичном виде, его будет легко использовать в виде обучающего материала для новых участников сообщества, а также без труда поддерживать и пополнять информацию в будущем.

Дополнительно к вопросу я создам графические баннеры, которые будут показываться в ротации и, если позволит текущий рекламный движок, выставлю ограничение по репутации от 1 балла и до, например, 500. Баннеры я предложил бы сделать по аналогии с «[Поможем коллегам сделать первый шаг к профессиональному росту](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2539/)», то есть иконка автора ответа–пояснения механики и заголовок цитатой (см. дальше). Буду рад улучшить любую из предложенных идей на основе ваших отзывов.

#### Требования к пояснениям

- *Одна подсказка — один ответ.* В ином случае на подсказку будут не сослаться баннером.
- *Краткость*. Чем меньше и короче подсказка, тем лучше. Будет здорово, если чтение подсказки не будет занимать более одной минуты.
- *Конкретность*. Пояснение механики — это конкретный пример использования сайта. Рекомендуется рассматривать пояснения на конкретных небольших примерах из «реальной жизни», то есть с основного сайта.
- *Наглядность*. Если речь идет об использовании какой–либо функции сайта, отличной идеей будет показать, где находится ссылка, куда нажимать, чего ожидать. Оформленные снимки экрана в ответе–пояснении помогут сориентироваться на целевой странице сайта и запомнить нужную информацию.
- *Лаконичность заголовка*. Каждая подсказка должна иметь короткий заголовок (5 — 7 слов), который однозначно говорит о чем идет речь в подсказке. Заголовок будет размещен на баннере.
- *Необходимые ссылки.* Если подсказка — это краткая выжимка из справки или другого вопроса, пожалуйста, не забудьте указать ссылку на источник, чтобы все желающие могли углубиться в тему.

---

Пожалуйста, помните, что детальное описание многих функций мы документируем в формате [faq–вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/faq). Если ваша подсказка Получилось развернутой, возможно, стоит опубликовать ее в виде отдельного faq–вопроса.

Поделитесь вашими идеями о инициативе в ответах на этот вопрос! Если у вас уже есть отличная идея для «пояснения», пожалуйста, опубликуйте ее сразу ответом к вопросу «[Подсказки о механиках работы Stack Overflow](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7020/6)».

Если люди будут понимать как устроен сайт и нашу конечную цель — создание сводной базы знаний в виде «проблема – решение», то они будут допускать меньше ошибок на старте и перестанут бояться принимать участие в жизни сообщества. Положительный первый опыт использования сайта — залог долгого и продуктивного участия в жизни сообщества!

---

**Обновление**: Запустили показ баннеров, ведущих на подсказки на Мете.

Comment: в тему: [Create a guided tour for new users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127182/137096)

Comment: по ссылке много текста, подведу итог: суть Stack Overflow: *"практичные ответы на типичные вопросы"* Всё что требуется от нового пользователя, чтобы информативный ответ получить: *"задать ясный, полезный вопрос"*. Всё остальное вторично¶ Вывод для текущей дискуссии: для большинства пользователей подсказки это препятствие на пути к решению их проблемы. Те люди, которые предрасположены подсказки читать, лучше прочтут [tag:faq] на Мете.

Comment: имел в виду: [meta-tag:faq]

Comment: @jfs Спасибо за ссылку! Бегло прочитал. Как я понял, речь идет о тур–подобных страницах. В отзывах ребята предлагали нечто иное — разместить подсказки в разных местах на сайте. Технически это будет крайне сложно и самый простой способ — баннеры. Теоретически, человек не должен отвлекаться. Он прочтет заголовок на баннере и только если он его привлечет, перейдет на страничку вопроса с рекомендациями. Это не обязательная активность для участников.

Answer (score 10):

Почему бы не использовать контекстные подсказки? Которые акцентируют внимание на конкретных элементах структуры страницы по мере необходимости в этом. Которые появляются по мере пользования сайтом, не заставляют человека отвлекаться и переходить на специальные страницы с тоннами информации, а быстро и кратко вводят его в курс дела.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, отличная идея! Надеюсь, в один день так и сделаем!

Answer (score 5):

Самым критичным моментом для новичков является непопадание в дух ресурса, когда вопрос закрывают, порой предварительно его заминусовав и (иногда) отшутившись в комментариях. Это обижает и разочаровывает новичков (*SO призывает не бояться задавать вопросы, "не бойся показаться не компетентным, зато получишь ответ",… но бьет после этого, порой, весьма больно…*).

Поэтому я предлагаю собрать в одну подсказку всё то, что приветствуется и не приветствуется в вопросах на SO. Этак, пройтись по пунктам [тура](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour), справочных страниц *[on-topic](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)* и *[how-to-ask](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)*, причинам закрытия и тревогам, а затем сгруппировать всё это по тройкам «как делать не надо», «как надо делать» и «как исправить (улучшить) вопрос, чтобы он перешёл из первого во второе». Также можно рассказать о  закрытии вопросов и когда его используют. Указать, что при внесении правки в вопрос он будет автоматически вынесен на голосование по переоткрытию, так что не надо думать, что закрытие — это приговор.

Вот только, похоже, это придётся оформить в виде видеоподсказки, ибо народ не любит читать длинные простыни текста.

Comment: Отличная идея! Единственное, надо бы как–то это разбить, чтобы «простыни текста» не было. Основная особенность подсказок в том, что ни короткие.

Comment: `ибо народ не любит читать длинные простыни текста` -- а смотреть видео любит? (я, например, ненавижу видео)

Comment: Народ любит картинки. Можно проиллюстрировать "что такое хорошо" и, разумеется, "что такое плохо".